# create a generic list from a non-generic list in run-time

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance, runtime

I have three classes:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
 //properties
}

public class Order:BaseEntity
{
 //properties
}

public class Customer:BaseEntity
{
 //properties
}
```

also i have a list that may fill with `Customer`s or fill with `Order`s:

```
IList nongenericList = SomeMethodGetObjects(); //this method return list of customers or list of Orders
```

is there any way to i detect `nongenericList` objects type in run-time and create Appropriate generic list(in runtime) and cast `nongenericList` to this created generic list?
for example if `nongenericList` contains Orders, it makes `List<Order>` and if `nongenericList` contain's Customers, it makes `List<Customer>`?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510781/generic-list-created-at-runtime

Comment: What is this nongeneric `List` class of which you speak? Can you provide a link to the MSDN documentation for it? Can you provide a code snippet that creates one?

Comment: Why do you not just make a ``List<BaseEntity>``?

Comment: You would at the very least have to iterate all the way through the list checking that every items was of the same type. And then you'd have make a new generic list of the right type and copy all the elements into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<BaseEntity> input= GetData();
foreach(BaseEntity item in input)
{
   if( item is Order)
      // Do Sth;
   else if( item is Customer)
      // Do sth else
}
```

Comment: This seems a better approach than messing around with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList nonGenericList = ......

List<Customer> genericList = nonGenericList.OfType<Customer>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this explcitly by creating different lists. if you want you can create all the lists at once or you could check for the type and then create the list of the base type.

example of creating a particular type of list.

```
List<Order> genericOrderList = nongenericlist.Where(x=>x is Order)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type and then cast it to relevant list.

```
  Type type = nongenericList[0].GetType();

    if (type.Equals(typeof(Customer)))
    {
        List<Customer> c = nongenericList.Cast<Customer>().ToList<Customer>();
    }
    else if (type.Equals(typeof(Order)))
    {
        List<Order> c = nongenericList.Cast<Order>().ToList<Order>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that all items in the list are of the same type:

```
if (nongenericList.Count == 0) {
  // no items
} else if (nongenericList[0] is Order) {
  List<Order> orders = nongenericList.Cast<Order>();
  // use the list here
} else {
  List<Customer> customers = nongenericList.Cast<Customer>();
  // use the list here
}
```